# Dragula draggable - reposition bootstrap grid system on drag: 2 divs on left, 1 on right

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, dragula

Im using dragula as a plugin for dragging div elements in a container.

If the sequence is col-md-9, col-md-3, col-md-3 it will look like this, there would be no problem

```
|-----------------|-------|
|                 |   2   |
|      1          |       |
|   (col-md-9)    |-------|
|                 |   3   |
|                 |       |
|-----------------|-------|
```

But when i drag the div elements in which case the sequence is col-md-3, col-md-9, col-md-3 I want the divs to look like this:

```
|-------|-----------------|
|   1   |                 |
|       |        2        |
|-------|    (col-md-9)   |
|   3   |                 |
|       |                 |
|-------|-----------------|
```

Not like this:

```
|-------|-----------------|
|   1   |                 |
|-------|        2        |
        |    (col-md-9)   |
        |                 |
        |                 |
        |-----------------|
|-------|
|   3   |
|-------|
```

I can't put the element 1 and 3 to a single col-md-3 since i need them to be dragged individually since each col-md-* is the draggable div
Here is the snippet code. I can use jquery or css. Thanks.

```
<div class="row inview dragula clearfix">

   <div class="col-md-12 clearfix">


   <div class="col-md-3 clearfix">
      <div class="box " style = "height:243px;border:4px dashed rgba(25,25,25,.5)">
         <div class="box-body  draggable handle">
            Shortcut
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>

   <div class="col-md-3 clearfix">
      <div class="box"  style = "height:243px;border:4px dashed rgba(25,25,25,.5)">
        <div class="box-body draggable handle">
          Shortcut 2
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>

   <div class="col-md-9 ">
      <div class="box"  style = "height:500px;border:4px dashed rgba(25,25,25,.5)">
         <div class="box-body draggable handle">
             Calendar
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>



 </div>
```